# Celery with Logbook

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm working on putting together a system that does it's logging through RabbitMQ (and ultimately writes to a database).  I found that the [Logbook](http://pythonhosted.org/Logbook/) library has a MessageQueueHandler (and RabbitMQHandler) that will write python logging into a message queue.  This appears to work great.  However when I try to digest these messages using a Celery worker with an associated task I'm getting an Unknown Message warning and it is then deleting that message without reading it:

```
[2015-06-16 15:59:06,688: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?
```

The full contents of the message body was:

```
body: {u'thread_name': u'MainThread', u'extra': {}, u'process': 11784, u'module': u'__main__', u'heavy_init
ialized': True, u'information_pulled': True, u'exception_message': None, u'message': u'test', u'exception_name': None, u'frame_correction': 0, u'filen
ame': u'<input>', u'lineno': 2, u'kwargs': {}, u'msg': u'test', u'channel': u'__main__', u'args': [], u'func_name': u'<module>', u'process_name': u'Ma
inProcess', u'formatted_exception': None, u'thread': 12904, u'level': 2, u'greenlet': 12904, u'time': u'2015-06-16T15:59:06.989000Z'} (502b)
{content_type:u'application/json' content_encoding:u'utf-8'
  delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': u'5', 'redelivered': False, 'routing_key': u'logging', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'exchange': u'logging'} headers={}}
```

There are 2 reasons I can think of that this is happening.  One is that the json in the message is not in Python format, so there are values like Null in it (instead of None) and true (instead of True).  The second reason I think this might be failing is because the message is being sent to the exchange (and routed to the queue) through Logbook instead of through a Celery task (that would be associated with the worker).

Is there a way to combine these two technologies so that the Logbook MessageQueueHandler can write to the message queue and a Celery worker can read from this queue?

**Edit Addition:**
Here is the tasks.py function that is being used by the celery worker to get the messages from the logging queue that is populated from Logbook's RabbitMQHandler class:

```
@shared_task
def digest_logs(logging_queue_data):
    for k,v in logging_queue_data.iteritems():
        print k, v
    completion_indicator = 'Complete'
    return completion_indicator
```

The celery command to run the worker is as follows:

```
celery -A proj.tasks worker --loglevel=debug -Q logging
```

Comment: it looks like you are putting logging messages on the celery queue - is that correct? can you post the celery task that consumes the log messages?

Comment: see additional edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a worker using Kombu rather than Celery for this, since with the Kombu library the code that writes the messages doesn't also have to be the code that listens for the messages (in other words you don't have to have the same code on both sides of the message queue).  So in the end there wasn't really a good way to use Celery for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have configured celery to listen to the queue that the logbook messages are being sent to. Celery expects them to be task messages (i.e. specifying a task to run) in its internal format.

The solution is to have separate queues for celery and logbook. I recommend using the default queue for celery - i.e. start the worker like this:

```
celery -A proj.tasks worker -Q celery
```

Then your celery task will have to read from the `logging` queue - in the task you would need to use one of the available libraries (`librabbitmq`, `amqp`, `puka`...) to read logbook messages from the `logging` queue.